# Which is good language for creating a webservice?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am making a application in Android which can show the product for selling. Hence, I need to use a webservice to manager and transfer data to Android app. I would like to know which is good language for me. Because I am beginner about webservice. My friend used PHP and he said it is good language. However, I need the manager and put the data to the web. For example, the user can be upload the image to the web.

Comment: PHP with resful service is good i think and it's work perfectly in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any tutorial for my task: upload image to service, and android can download/get link or get data from webservice

Comment: chek it out this ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026825/get-images-from-php-server-to-android

Answer (score 2):

Language is not so important - important "brains" of the programmer.

Comment: Thank. I think that the webservice need to support two things: first upload to server. Second, download the image or the link of the image

Comment: Ruby on Rails and gem Paperclip - good option

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you really want to do with the webservice. If all you want is an endpoint for your Android application, I'd recommend nodejs, which is pretty useful for small little server side applications, and it is all javascript (pretty much) so you don't have to learn a new language (probably).

If you want the API combined with a backoffice in which you can log in and do all kinds of stuff, I'd recommend c#. In .net you can make a pretty neat backoffice pretty quickly, and a seperate API project that uses the same resources as your backoffice.

If you don't know c# you can use php instead, though coming from someone that is experienced with both languages, .net is just more comfortable.

Comment: My task included two things: First: android app will upload a image to the webservice, It will save the image in server. The other android app can download the link (JSON format)

Comment: This is what an API would do, you send the link to some url connecting to your server. The server handles your request by saving the image, or by retreiving the image. If all you need to do and want for this in the future, I'd go with nodejs

Comment: I want to send image directly. I want to use php

Comment: If you're saying you want to use php, why are you asking this question?